# how to hide a hyperlink from visible while take printout in php/javascript

Tags: php, javascript, css, printing, hyperlink

I would like a hyperlink to be hidden when taking the print of that page(the hyperlink is using to print the page) either by CSS/javascript/PHP

Answer (score 5):

use CSS:

```
@media print{
  a{
     display: none;
  }
}
```

and put inside the print{} brackets whatever you want to show/hide while printing. Whatever is inside those squirly brackets will only be applied when a page is printed :)

To test that better, you should first make the page how u want it to show for print, using normal css, then wrap that in a @media print{} :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **css media types** for that. Take a look at this links:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html
- http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cssmedia.shtml
- http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/css/mediatypes